# GTM Cross Domain displaying data for all sites on each property.

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I set up cross-domain tracking so that a user's session would be followed as they pass through each of the sites we own. After it was done being set up, and I go in to review my properties, I'm seeing data from sites B, C, and D for the property I have set up for Site A.

How do I keep these properties individualized?

Comment: If you are using separate Google Analytics properties for each site, why are you trying to use cross-domain tracking?    It would only make sense to use cross-domain tracking if all domains use the same GA property.  [Google's documentation says](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en): "For cross-domain tracking, set up **one** property in your Analytics account. Use the same tracking code snippet and tracking ID from that property for all of your domains."

Comment: @StephenOstermiller ...because I want to see how users travel between all my sites. But I also want to know which users view Site A, but not Site B, etc. Does that make sense?

Additionally, I'm not using GA. I'm using GTM and I have the cross domain tracking set up in my variables.

Comment: You tagged your question with Google analytics.  You don't need cross domain to see how users go between sites.  Just normal referral info would be enough for that

Comment: It's tagged with GA because you can't use GTM without GA. Your comment about not needing it doesn't make sense. Why would Google create the software? Moving on...

Comment: I didn't say you don't need GTM or GA.   I said you don't need to implement cross-domain-tracking.  In fact you shouldn't implement it if you are using different GA properties.

Comment: Alright. I'll keep plugging away at it then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you implement x-domain tracking with gtm and ga you use the same ga property for all included domains. That will make all your data wind up in the same view.

Next you add a view for each domain you are tracking so you can separate the data. Name the view according to the domain so you can keep track of them.
In each view add a filter to only display visitor data for that particualar domain. 
Now you have the data separate.

Last you create a roll-up view, still in the same property in ga. Here you allow all domains to send their data so you can see the whole visitor journey.